# How to convert a Cross Apply to a Pivot for Performance reasons

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, cross-apply

I have a query as shown below. It runs great for the first hundred or so rows but once I start to scale it, it falls flat on its face.  After checking the Query Plan, It is what I expected, the cross apply on a TVF is the root cause.   The TFV is a very in depth function but on its own, it runs at 0ms.  But once I throw it into a Cross Apply, I am getting 18 seconds for 170 records but the strange thing is with 280 records, I still get 18 seconds.   I was reading that I could convert the Cross Apply to a Pivot and was wondering how I would do that.  Here is the code.

```
SELECT 
    P.prno_id
    ,C.client_id as [ClientID]
    ,E.enco_id as [Encounter]
    ,C.fname + ' ' + C.lname as [Patient]
    ,PL.prle_listname as [Program]
    ,t.PreDate as [RXDate]
    ,t.RxNumber as [RxNumber] 
    ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(t.RxPrice, '$') = 0 THEN '$' ELSE '' END + t.RxPrice as [Price]
    ,t.RXNotes as [Notes]
    ,t.RxStatus as [Status]
FROM Progress_Note P
JOIN Encounter E 
    on E.enco_id = P.enco_id
JOIN client_program CP 
    on CP.clpr_id = dbo.Sundown_func_Get_Admission_Program_By_Encounter(E.enco_id)
JOIN PROGRAM_LEVEL PL 
    on PL.prle_id = CP.prle_id
JOIN Client 
    C on C.client_id = P.client_id
Cross Apply dbo.Sundown_func_Get_HTML_Table_Results_test(P.prno_id)  as t
```

I have tried looking at indexing but the TVF does not use anything that would need to be indexed, its purely calculations of a Table and coverts it.  I really just want to try our PIVOT as a replacement for the Cross Apply.

Comment: If your function have multiple steps (ie. non-inlined Table valued function), the performance will usually be bad, so the best would be to convert it to inline function first, if you can't, then you're probably stuck already. I'm not sure where you've seen that pivot can help with anything. Maybe if you post the function, someone can help you, or at least enjoy the code. Also, query plans for functions are usually misleading, so it's not necessary that the function is the main culprit

Comment: `CROSS APPLY` is a lateral join. It is used to join the rows produced by the function based on a value in another table. You need this join to get your rows. `PIVOT` comes later. It is invoked on the result set you already have. It cannot replace a join. `PIVOT` can replace conditional aggregation, but there is no aggregation in your query.